# node_modules\keytar npm ERR! command failed

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am keep on getting below error. Can anyone please help.

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\WebApp\NPulseWeb\node_modules\keytar
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || npm run build
npm ERR! > keytar@7.9.0 build
npm ERR! > node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! prebuild-install warn install self-signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.16.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.13 found at "C:\Users\Etest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.16.0/node-v18.16.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\path\to\your\cert.pem'
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\WebApp\NPulseWeb\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\WebApp\NPulseWeb\node_modules\keytar
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.16.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

Comment: npm ERR! path C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@azure\static-web-apps-cli\node_modules\keytar
npm ERR! command failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue got resolved now. I have uninstalled all apps and installed all required apps in Admin mode and installed at system level instead of user.